# Adding name and other title at the bottom of each slide in beamer

Tags: footnotes, author

I am trying to create a presentation in beamer. I want to add the name of university and my name at the bottom of each slide that I have seen in other presentations. But I am unable to add it with my existing code. How to resolve this?

```
\documentclass[english,svgnames,notes=hide,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{braket}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\setbeamertemplate{headline}

\def\presentationtitle{Testing the black-hole area law with GW150914}

\title[]{\large\presentationtitle}
\author[]{Pk, Ak }
\subtitle{}
\date{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}




\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Introduction}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Something like `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\strut \insertshortinstitute \hfill \insertshortauthor}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what You need?

```
\documentclass[english,svgnames,notes=hide,12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{braket}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\def\presentationtitle{Testing the black-hole area law with GW150914}


\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}

\begin{document}

\title[11]{The title1}
\author[11]{autor1}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\title[222]{The title2}
\author[222]{autor2}
\begin{frame}{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```